# Bug with button on Phonegap/Cordova apps and Android 4.4.3 KitKat (fast click?)

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

We are experiencing problems with our phonegap / cordova apps on Android 4.4.3. It was working well on all the previous version of KitKat, but now, the buttons of our apps are not working well anymore:

-> we have to click several time in order to let the click happens. It's like the click/touch are not always registered

We are using Intel App Framework V2.0.4 and cordova 3.4

Maybe it's a problem of fast click and ontouchstart/end, because .the Android 4.4.3 has a lot of changes regarding events.

Comment: For those interested, updating Intel App Framework fixed it.